# ein fails when emacs tries to connect to ipython/jupyter server

Tags: emacs, proxy, jupyter-notebook

I'm behind a firewall and emacs uses a proxy server for HTTP and HTTPS protocols.
I have installed the *ein* package (*emacs*, *ipython* and *notebook*) using *el-get*. I then started the ipython/jupyter server.

Now trying  `M-x ein:notebooklist-open` in Emacs **Using a proxy for http** raises below errors:

> ein: [error] Kernelspc query call failed with status error.
>     ein: [error] Content list call `http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/contents/` failed with status error.
>       REQUEST [error] Error (error) while connecting to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/contents`.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First you must login using:

```
M-x ein:notebooklist-login
```

type in the port number (usually :8888 ) , then the token or set password and only then:

```
M-x ein:notebooklist-open
```